# Can ExtJS 3.x and ExtJS 5 co-exist in a single application?

Tags: user-interface, extjs, web-applications, extjs3, extjs5

I'm not a developer myself, but my company develops and supports a large web application for  insurance brokers.

Since way back we've been using ExtJS 3.x and as we went further the harder it got to migrate from 3.x to 4 and now to ExtJS 5. Due to the structure of the application and demands from out customers we cannot afford to freeze development and focus on refactoring our interfaces.

But we still want to use the benefits and functionality of the ExtJS 5.

My question is - is it possible to use both versions of the framework in the same application? For example, developing new grids and modules with ExtJS 5 and gradually migrating existing forms.

Did anybody have this sort of experience? Or is it plain nonsense and will never work?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this question very interesting. I had a similar challenge, when I had to migrate our in house app from legacy Jxlib to ExtJs4. Putting my experience together with @Lolo's answer here is what I can advice:

**Build on a new solid foundation.** You could be tempted to keep your app in ExtJs 3.0 and start grafting new ExtJs 5.0 components on it. If you really want to take advantage of all the new features of ExtJs 5.0, you should start off with a clean, simple MVC app in ExtJs 5.0, that could be as little as the main window and the main menu. You could then bind all existing menu entries to the existing ExtJs 3.0 code. This will allow you to start with a really clean thing, keeping all the old functionality, without rewriting the code, and allow you to develop all new features with clean ExtJs 5.0 code that follows current best practice recommendations.

You will face two stumbling blocks:

1. **You have to separate the namespaces** in Javascript and CSS. Here also, I would advice to change the prefixes for ExtJs 3.0, and not for Ext 5.0 (I ignore if ExtJs 5.0 includes a sandbox file). The reason behind is that all your new ExtJs 5.0 code will be standard compatible, while only the old legacy code becomes incompatible (what it is anyway already). This will represent some code refactoring though, because you would need to replace all `Ext.` occurrencies in all your code with `Ext3.` or similar (the same applies to CSS, but will be much less work). I hope for you, that ExtJs 3.0 has a sandbox version, because I think refactoring their code would be a lot of work (but not impossible).
2. A major feature of ExtJs 5.0 (as already for version 4.x) is the **automatic building and compiling of an MVC application using `Sencha Cmd`**. This didn't exist yet for ExtJs 3.0. I think it is crucial that you start straight away using this tool. I will allow you to really take advantage of all the enhancements (declarative programming instead of imperative, advanced MVC and MVVM features). It will radically change your coding style.
   To get this work, you compile in a first step you old code in one Javascript file. Sencha Cmd must not recognize this as an Ext app. Then you simply add `requires: 'Oldapp'` in `Application.js` and ExtJs will include a file called `Oldapp.js`. That file should define a class `Oldapp` and include all the rest of your application code:

   ```
   Ext.define('Oldapp', {
       // Just what ever you need
   })
   // All the rest of the code of you old app
   ```

   Then layout all the folders and files of your new code according to the MVC or MVVM specification (whatever you prefer) in the Ext doc, and Sencha Cmd will build you the whole app correctly.

I think this all allows you to take advantage of all the new features immediately, building on a clean, standard foundation with only minor code refactoring. It sounds like eat the cake and have it too, but it is possible.

**But this will take a huge mental step**: You must learn ExtJs 5.0 like something new and try to forget all you know already about ExtJs. You won't use `Ext.ready` anymore, `Ext.Loader` will handle this under the hood. Nor will you instantiate Ext objects from declarations (ban `panel = Ext.create({xtype: 'panel', ...` stuff), stick to `Ext.define('Myapp.view.Mypanel' ...`. There are many other points where everything changed since Ext 3.0 ...

This last point is in my opinion the biggest stumbling block, much more important than the two technical points explained before: **It is difficult, but crucial to reeducate yourself**.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lorenz! As I've said before, I'm not a programmer myself, but I do understand the concepts. I'll discuss the suggestions with my development team and if any questions or thoughts arrive, I won't be shy and I'll ask away again :). Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

You can use sandbox version of Ext Js 5.0 and "normal" 3.0 (I don't remember if 3.0 is also available as sandbox). 
Then you can change prefix for all 5.0 classes and css rules. By default it is `Ext4` (not Ext5) for JS, and `x4-` for CSS.
To use sandbox include `ext-all-sandbox.js` file from `build` directory.

Answer (score -1):

It won't work. The javascript files will clash with each other.